# Can't find the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Package for Excel 2016

Tags: c#, excel, package, nuget

I am trying to run a macro in Excel 2016 using a C# program from Visual Studio 2019. Here is what the beginning of this program looks like (just trying to open the workbook):

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace CurrentStudyRun
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            ApplicationClass objExcel = new ApplicationClass();
            objExcel.Visible = true;
            Workbooks workbooks = objExcel.Workbooks;
            Workbook oBook = null;

            oBook = workbooks.Open("path");


        }
    }
}
```

In order to do this, I installed he VSTO workload from the Visual Studio installer
[(Workload Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yrpI.png) and added the [Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd6PN.png). However, when I go to add the Nuget Package, I only see ones for Excel 2013 [as shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5Myg.png). What I get when using the top package is the error shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roWaQ.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solved***
The checklist was helpful so definitely do those things if you are having this problem but what ended up solving this for me was changing the Embed Interop Types for the references you are using to True. Do this by:

1. Right clicking on the dependency (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in this case) and selecting properties
2. Change Embed Interop Types to 'Yes' (mine had nothing selected)

Thank you for the answers Peter and Arya.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Excel 2016 and my test was successful.

#### Checklist

1. Check the imported dll are in the folder
   1.1) if you don't find them all put them in the bin folder manually
2. Microsoft Excel should be installed in your machine,
   2.1) and Microsoft products have valid licenses
3. If previous attempts failed then try to register the DLL in GAC